# How common are the card rarities in Arena?

Tags: hearthstone

In Arena, you are shown 30 set of 3 cards. Each set of 3 cards usually (always?) has the same card rarity. The card rarities are basic, common, rare, epic, and legendary.

How common are each of the rarities in Arena? In particular, are common and basic the same rarity or not?

The distribution of rarities in Arena must be different than the distribution of rarities in card packs because:

- Basic cards don't appear in card packs
- 1st, 10th, 20th, and 30th pick in Arena are always rare or higher
- Each card pack has at least one rare or higher

Comment: definately not always the same. I've had basic-basic-common and I think basic-basic-rare before.

Comment: Basic and common for sure, not sure I've seen basic and rare.

Comment: Perhaps basic-basic-common happens because basic and common are considered the same for Arena?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is according to my own experience. I have 257 arena wins and I like to keep stats. I searched previously but couldn't find an official source for this.

1st, 10th, 20th, 30th pick in Arena are always rare or higher: I call this Rare Turn, the others are normal turns.

At any normal turn, you can get one of these sets:

- 3 free
- 2 free 1 common
- 1 free 2 common
- (possibly 3 common as well didn't pay attention, can't verify this)
- 1 Rare turn ( % not sure I would guess about 5% - 10%)

In a normal turn roughly you have a 60% chance of getting a free and 40% chance of getting a common card.

At any rare turn, you can get one of these sets:

- 3 rare
- 3 epic
- 3 legendary

I got a legendary about every 10 games and since we have 4 rare+ picks I assume the chance of getting a legendary in a single rare turn is about 2%

I got an epic about every game so I assume the percentage for that is about 20%

**TL;DR:**

Normal Turn:

- Free      : 60%
- Common    : 40%

Rare Turn:

- Rare+     : 4 times
- Epic      : 20%
- Legendary : 2%

I don't have a source for this its all according to my personal experience. These numbers are most likely wrong, but should give the general idea. More data is needed for better estimates.

In a normal arena deck you will have something like this:

- 15 Free
- 10 Common
- 4 Rare
- 1 Epic/Legendary

Of course if you are lucky you could get 4 legendaries, 10 rares, etc..

Comment: So, you are saying that the Normal Turns _never_ give rare or above?

Comment: should be clearer now i hope

Comment: I plan to test this and comment back with my results.  I am surprised I have never noticed or paid attention to this before and now I am curious. Good question and answer.

Comment: I could've sworn I had common/rare mix before.  But I also haven't paid too much attention.  Next time if I come across this I'll take a SS

Comment: @z- I do not believe you would have ever had a common/rare mix in one pick.  I never have and I think it is setup to give you 3 choices from one rarity level.  Commons are mixed with the "Free" (basic) cards though.  Also, while you always get a rare or better on those 5 picks Esq noted, you also can get Rare+ on the other picks. Last night I had Rare pick on 1,7,10,20 Epic on 15,30 and Legendary on 8. Though I would say I get legendaries more often than 1 in 10 arenas. Probably 1 out of every 7 or 8.